# How to properly server static files from a Flask server?

Tags: flask, static-files

What is the proper way of serving static files (images, PDFs, Docs etc) from a flask server?

I have used the `send_from_directory` method before and it works fine. Here is my implementation:

```
@app.route('/public/assignments/<path:filename>')
def file(filename):
    return send_from_directory("./public/assignments/", filename, as_attachment=True)
```

However if I have multiple different folders, it can get a bit hectic and repetitive because you are essentially writing the same code but for different file locations - meaning if I wanted to display files for a user instead of an assignment, I'd have to change it to `/public/users/<path:filename>` instead of `/public/assignments/<path:filename>`.

The way I thought of solving this is essentially making a `/file/<path:filepath>` route, where the `filepath` is the entire path to the destination folder + the file name and extension, instead of just the file name and extension. Then I did some formatting and separated the parent directory from the file itself and used that data when calling the `send_from_directory` function:

```
@app.route('/file/<path:filepath>', methods=["GET"])
def general_static_files(filepath):
    filepath = filepath.split("/")
    _dir = ""
    for i, p in enumerate(filepath):
        if i < len(filepath) - 1:
            _dir = _dir + (p + "/")
    return send_from_directory(("./" + _dir), filepath[len(filepath) - 1], as_attachment=True)
```

if we simulate the following request to this route:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/file/public/files/jobs/images/job_43_image_1.jpg
```

the `_dir` variable will hold the `./public/files/jobs/images/` value, and then `filepath[len(filepath) - 1]` holds the `job_43_image_1.jpg` value.

If i hit this route, I get a `404 - Not Found` response, but all the code in the route body is being executed.

I suspect that the `send_from_directory` function is the reason why I'm getting a `404 - Not Found`. However, I do have the image `job_43_image_1.jpg` stored inside the `/public/files/jobs/images/` directory.

I'm afraid I don't see a lot I can do here except hope that someone has encountered the same issue/problem and found a way to fix it.

Here is the folder tree:

```
├── [2050]  app.py
├── [2050]  public
│   ├── [2050]  etc
│   └── [2050]  files
│       ├── [2050]  jobs
│       │   ├── [2050]  files
│       │   └── [2050]  images
│       │       ├── [2050]  job_41_image_decline_1.jpg
│       │       ├── [2050]  job_41_image_decline_2554.jpg
│       │       ├── [2050]  ...
│       ├── [2050]  shop
│       └── [2050]  videos
└── [2050]  server_crash.log
```

Edit 1: I have set up the `static_url_path`. I have no reason to believe that that could be the cause of my problem.

Edit 2: Added tree

Comment: @Patch I am running a local environment. In the boilerplate env I have created a `server` folder which is home to a `routes` folder, `models` folder, `public` folder and the `app.py` itself.

Comment: Since the `app.py` and the `public` folder share the same parent, there shouldnt be an issue, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass these arguments when you initialise the app:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='public',
                      static_url_path='frontend_public' )
```

This would make the file `public/blah.txt` available at `http://example.com/frontend_public/blah.txt`.

- **`static_folder`** sets the folder on the filesystem
- **`static_url_path`** sets the path used within the URL

If neither of the variables are set, it defaults to `'static'` for both.

Hopefully this is what you're asking.